# How to make searchview fill the remaining space?

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I want to display two icons and a search view in my app's action bar. I am using the support `Toolbar` and a `NoActionBar` theme. I am trying to put one icon to the left side and one to the right side, then put the `SearchView` in between, taking all the remaining space in between.

Custom settings applied to the `SearchView`:

- `app:iconifiedByDefault="false"` (so that the view is expanded by default)
- `app:searchIcon="@drawable/search_action_bar_icon"` (the search icon)

What I have already tried:

**1. No stylling applied:**

In this case, the searchview doesn't strech enough because it has set a maximum width by default.

[image: The appearance of the action bar, first attempt]

**2. Maximum width increased**

Then, I increased the maximum width to a very high value (10000dp), so that it could expand freely. With the width set to either `match_parent` or `wrap_content`, the search view took all the remaining space to the right, so the second icon went off-screen.

[image: The appearance of the action bar, first attempt]

**3. Using `layout_weigth`**

Using a layout inspector, I discovered that the view group holding the menu items is an `ActionMenuView`, the superclass of which is `LinearLayoutCompat`. The proposed solution to achieve the desired outcome in a LinearLayout is to set the width of the middle child to `0dp` and its `layout_weight` to `1` while other children preserve a fixed width. However, the `SearchView` came out only 0dp wide, which possibly means that the width of the `ActionMenuView` is set to `wrap_content` - I'm not sure about this to be honest.

[image: The appearance of the action bar, third attempt]

So, what to do to achieve this:

[image: The desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well this is the solution I am aware of - not to use menu items but rather a custom view for the app bar, but that's not how I wanted to solve this